# Animation rendering using Nodejs on backend server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, createjs, easeljs

I have simple animation created using create js and ffmpegserver.js.

ffmpegserver.js.

This is a simple node server and library that sends canvas frames to the server and uses FFmpeg to compress the video. It can be used standalone or with CCapture.js.

Here is repo: [video rendering demo](https://github.com/throne1986/video-rendering).

on folder public, I have demos eg test3.html and test3.js

Test3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TweenJS: Simple Tween Demo</title>
<style>

canvas {
          border: 1px solid #08bf31;
          justify-content: center;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin: 0px auto;
          margin-bottom: 40px;
      }

      a {
        width: 150px;
        height: 45px;
        background: red;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 300px;
        color: white;
      }
      #container{
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
    #progress{
        margin: 30px;
    }
    #preview{
        margin: 40px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 45px;
        background: deepskyblue;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 300px;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body onload="init();">

<div>

<div id="container">
        <h1>Simple Tween Demo</h1>
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://localhost:8081/ffmpegserver/CCapture.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8081/ffmpegserver/ffmpegserver.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.js"></script>
<script src="test3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test3.js

```
/* eslint-disable eol-last */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable quotes */
var canvas, stage;
    function init() {
        var framesPerSecond = 60;
        var numFrames = framesPerSecond * 5; // a 5 second 60fps video
        var frameNum = 0;

        var progressElem = document.getElementById("progress");
        var progressNode = document.createTextNode("");
        progressElem.appendChild(progressNode);

        function onProgress(progress) {
          progressNode.nodeValue = (progress * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        }

        function showVideoLink(url, size) {
          size = size ? (" [size: " + (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(1) + "meg]") : " [unknown size]";
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = url;
          var filename = url;
          var slashNdx = filename.lastIndexOf("/");
          if (slashNdx >= 0) {
            filename = filename.substr(slashNdx + 1);
          }
          a.download = filename;
          a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Download"));
          var container = document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(a, progressElem);

        }

        var capturer = new CCapture( {
          format: 'ffmpegserver',
          //workersPath: "3rdparty/",
          //format: 'gif',
          //verbose: true,
          framerate: framesPerSecond,
          onProgress: onProgress,
          //extension: ".mp4",
          //codec: "libx264",
        } );
        capturer.start();


        canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
        stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
        var ball = new createjs.Shape();
        ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(5, 'round', 'round');
        // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
        ball.graphics.beginStroke('#000000');
        ball.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1, 'round', 'round');
        ball.graphics.beginStroke('#000000');
        ball.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
        ball.graphics.lineTo(0, 50);
        ball.graphics.endStroke();
        ball.x = 200;
        ball.y = -50;
        createjs.Tween.get(ball, {loop: -1})
            .to({x: ball.x, y: canvas.height - 55, rotation: -360}, 1500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
            .wait(1000)
            .to({x: canvas.width - 55, rotation: 360}, 2500, createjs.Ease.bounceOut)
            .wait(1000)
            .to({scaleX: 2, scaleY: 2}, 2500, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
            .wait(1000)
        stage.addChild(ball);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            capturer.capture( canvas );

            ++frameNum;
            if (frameNum < numFrames) {
            progressNode.nodeValue = "rendered frame# " + frameNum + " of " + numFrames;
            } else if (frameNum === numFrames) {
            capturer.stop();
            capturer.save(showVideoLink);
            }
        }

        render();
}
```

Everything works fine, you can test it yourself if you want by cloning the repo.

Right now animation rendering happens in client side, I would like this animation rendering to happen in the backend side

What do I need to change to make this animation rendering in backend server side using Nodejs? any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)?

Comment: Eric no  I didn't, I am not familiar with it, do you think it can solve my problem ?

Comment: i think so, it is a headless chrome browser and puppeteer is the control interface, so basically you have programmatic access to a full browser

Comment: any one out there?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do all your animations in the canvas, you can use [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to do the same in Node.js. (You have to double check that create.js also work in Node.js, though. If not, find another library or write those routines yourself).

Spawn ffmpeg into it's own process accepting input through a pipe (`ffmpeg -i - -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba` etc. The pipe will probably be different according to which server environment you use). After each frame is drawn, extract the image array using `canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data` and pipe the result to to ffmpeg.