# Upload CCapture.js gif to Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, p5.js

So I'm currently working on a project in which I try to save my .gif on a node.js, linux based server. The gif is created by ccapture.js  in combination with p5.js . Problem is, that `capturer.save()` alone does download the gif to the users download folder (I work with gif.worker.js btw). The idea is, that the gif gets uploaded into a specific folder automatically after creation.

I was currently trying out stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864251/how-to-run-ccapture-by-server-side-node-js) but then I could not use my p5 Canvas anymore right?

Another thing I tried, keeping above link in mind, was:

```
const NUM_FRAMES = 30;
const T = 1;
const FORMAT = 'gif';
const FPS = 60;
const FRAMELIMIT = 5 * FPS;
const WORKERSFOLDER = '../image/libraries/';

var capturer = new CCapture({ format: FORMAT, workersPath: WORKERSFOLDER, framerate: FPS, framelimit: FRAMELIMIT });
```

```
if (capture) {
        capturer.capture(canvas); // if capture is 'true', save the frame
        if (frameCount - 1 == NUM_FRAMES) { //stop and save after NUM_FRAMES
            capturer.stop();
            capturer.save( blob => {
            const reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
                const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                const fs = require('fs');
                const dir = '../../data/json';
                let n = fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
                files.length + 1
                });
                // Sync for simplicity
                fs.writeFile(`../../data/gifs/${n}.gif`, uint8Array, { encoding: "binary" }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('error', err);
                });
            }}
            );
            noLoop();
        }
    }
```

But currently it just finishes creating the give and tells me the size. Nothing happens after that.
I hoped it does work with `fs.writeFile` alone, but if you guys have good ideas I am all ears.

I am no programmer so I don't really know what I am doing here. It is way above my skillset :D

---

EDIT:

So I try clarifying my goal and problem here:
my idea with [ccapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/) is to create a gif of my p5canvas. This works fine when just using the `capturer.save();` as it downloads the file as {name}.extension automatically afterwards.
This I do **not** want though! Instead I want it to save directly into a directory of my Server (lets make it `const dir = '../../data/json';`). But this is the problem I face. In the other question linked above, one answer said ccapture.js is not able to do this and so the commenter edited it with JSDOM and its canvas to work. This is also where I got my obscure `blob` from.
I *(assume)* cannot use the JSDOM though because then I would have to deviate from the p5canvas, which I need to show my stuff..

Question arises if there is a way to do this, or is there maybe an alternative to ccapture.js I just don't know of, which does just that?

Basic Setup is:

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="./image/libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./image/libraries/CCapture.min.js"></script>
    <link href="./image/libraries/gif.worker.js">
    <script src="./image/libraries/CCapture.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./image/myShader.js"></script>
    <script src="./image/imageComponent.js"></script> <!-- my p5 code with CCapture inside-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvasDiv"> <!-- CANVAS -->
    </div>
</body>
```

P5JS:

```
function setup() {
    var p5Canvas = createCanvas(1080, 1080, WEBGL);
    p5Canvas.parent("canvasDiv");
    noStroke()
    myShader = createShader(vert, frag);
    shader(myShader);
}

function draw() {

    if (capture && frameCount == 1) {
        capturer.start(); // start the animation capture
    // and some visual code stuff
    // code from above
    }
```

Hope this clears it up a bit. I don't know how to mak a *minimal reproducible example* for this one.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you in the browser or Node? Where's `window` coming from in Node? Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen to be honest with you, I am not sure about the whole `blob` function in that code snippet.
Clarification: I am hosting those files over a node.js server and reaching out to it via browser. To edit it, I use a SSH connection via VSC. Hope that explains like literally anything.

As far as a minimal reproducible example goes I am not sure. I mean It is basically ccapture.js standard I want to change if thta makes sense. I will try to create something

Comment: Well, ccapture runs in the browser, as does p5.js, right? But fs and reading/writing files is a node thing. So I still can't wrap my head around how the code is supposed to work in either environment. You probably need to ccapture the blob, then make an HTTP request to your Node server (which is running, say, Express.js) which will then write the file to your server's file system.

Comment: Maybe I have to do a `fetch({method: "POST",})`. But as of writing this. no luck